# Sort a JSON alphabetically using JQuery and print to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

So I am trying to take a json and sort it alphabetically, then create tables and place the information dynamically into their respective tables. I can't seem to get them to sort alphabetically. Below is my JQuery:

```
<script>
function populateDept(){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sslmd5y53uusgfx/depts.json',
            data: { get_param: 'value' },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                 $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    data.sort(function(a,b){
                    return a[1] > b[1] ? 1: -1;
                  });

                    var classAcr ="." + element.acronym;
                    $('#content').prepend($('<table class="aui aui-sortable">').addClass(element.acronym + ""));
                    $(classAcr).append($('<thead>').css("text-align", "left").append($('<tr>').append($('<th>', {
                        text: element.name
                    })).append($('<th>', {
                        text: element.acronym
                    }))));
                     for (var i = 0; i < element.departments.length; i++) {
                        $(classAcr).append($('<tr>').append($('<td>', {
                            text: element.departments[i].name
                        })).append($('<td>', {
                            text: element.departments[i].acronym
                        })));
                    }
                });
                $("th").css("width","50%");
                $("th").css("width","50%");
                $("table").append("<br>");
                $("th").css("font-weight", "bold");
                $("th").css("font-size", "35px");
            }
        });
      }
   populateDept();
</script>
```

The json I am working with looks like this, but has more departments listed. I am trying to sort them by "name" :"Academic Affairs" ect.

```
[{
"name": "Academic Affairs",
"acronym": "ACAD",
"departments": [{
    "name": "International Education and Global Programs",
    "acronym": "IEGP"
},
{
    "name": "Graduate Studies",
    "acronym": "GRAD"
},
{
    "name": "RIT Honors Program",
    "acronym": "Honors"
},
{
    "name": "Institute Advising",
    "acronym": "IADV"
},
{
    "name": "Innovative Learning Institute",
    "acronym": "ILI"
},
{
    "name": "K12 Programs",
    "acronym": "K12"
},
{
    "name": "Office of the Registrar",
    "acronym": "RGR"
},
{
    "name": "RIT Online",
    "acronym": "RITO"
},
{
    "name": "Study Abroad Program",
    "acronym": "SAP"
},
{
    "name": "Student Learning Outcomes Assessment",
    "acronym": "SLOA"
},
{
    "name": "School of Individualized Study",
    "acronym": "SOIS"
},
{
    "name": "Teaching and Learning Studio",
    "acronym": "TLS"
},
{
    "name": "University Studies Program",
    "acronym": "USP"
},
{
    "name": "University Writing Program",
    "acronym": "UWP"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort your object array by name try this one:

```
var jsonArray; //your json array
jsonArray.sort(function(a,b){
   returb a.name > b.name;
});
```

[array sorting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp)